# Returning a class instance in an (aspect)interface method

Tags: java, interface, aspectj, aop, implements

I am implementing an interface from an an aspect

```
declare parents: SomePackage.AClass+ extends InterfaceBelow

public interface InterfaceBelow() {
        //bunch of methods
}
```

I want a method which should return the class/instance implementing the interface itself. Something such as adding a method to the interface `public Object getSelf()` and then use AspectJ to implement it like this:

```
public InterfaceBelow.getSelf()
{
     //how to return the instance implementing the interface
}
```

I need to do it in the aspect not from the class and then `{return this;}`

Answer (score 1):

have `InterfaceBelow.getSelf()` return null. then create an `around` pointcut around that method. the pointcut can capture the `target` of the method invocation. return that instead.